# Why can't I put background images using "background-image" property?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a background on a div using a method that I've been always using ever since. But for some reason, it isn't working. These are the things I tried:

1. Checked the syntax, its correct
2. Checked the path or typo, although I copied the path from the security tab in the properties of the image
3. Putting different elements inside, even though I already have sub divs inside.
4. I also tried this property to other divs and the body, still nothing.
5. I removed the bg image property and tried bg color instead, it worked.

CSS:

```
#menu-container{
width: 100%;
height: 800px;
margin-top: 760px;
background-image: url("C:\Users\aaron\Desktop\MODULES\WEB301\WEB301(HTML)\media files\bg.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot load an image from `C:\`

However if you add `file:///` to your path like `file:///C:/Users/.....jpg` this might work in some Browsers (not all). Otherwise you will have to use relative paths. This means you reference the JPG in relevance to where the HTML or CSS file is sitting.

[Read this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) for more details about relative pathing.

Comment: I tried to use the relative path and it worked! Thanks a lot. :)

I really want to know why that didn't work when I try it like how  I know it should work. This is just a project which folders and file organization dont matter much because it's a small one. But I know that I should put files in their own folders to organize them because that's going to help me with bigger projects, as I have done many big ones.

Comment: You're welcome @AaronAncheta !
I'm not sure as I can't see what you previously tried, just remember to avoid using direct local paths (ie: ``C:\...``).